# About Big O Notation (N*N?)

Tags: math, big-o, computer-science

I have a few problems that I'm trying to find the Big O for. The ones that are confusing me are the (N*N) problems:

```
for (i=1, sum=0, i <= N; i++) {
  for (j=1; j <= N*N; j++) {
     sum++;
  }
}
```

I'm guess that it's O(N^3) since (N*N) could be representing two loops.

```
for (i=1, sum=0, i <= N; i++) {
  for (j=1; j <= N*N; j++) {
     for (k=1; k<=j; k++) {
       sum++;
     }
  }
}
```

If so, then this one would be O(N^4)?

Comment: `N*N` _is_ `n^2`.  Here's a very basic reference: http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: In the innermost loop in the second example, it's using a limit to `k` which is a function of `j`, so I'd say the answer might be closer to `O(N^3*log(N))`

Comment: @TrippKinetics `1+2+3+...+n` = `O(n²)`, so I doubt there's a `log` involved there.

Comment: Yes, but look at the innermost loop of the second example.  It doesn't use `1, 2, 3... n`.  It uses `1, 2, 3... j` where `j` goes `1, 2, 3... n^3`.

Comment: Duke is right, remember Big-Oh is upper bound.  The equation is upper bounded by N^5 (Inner loop = N^2, Mid loop = N^2 Outer loop = N.)  Tripp, remember that the first time the loop runs 1, then 2, then 3.  All the way up to 2N.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (i=1, sum=0, i <= N; i++) {  // loop over i
  for (j=1; j <= N*N; j++) {     // loop over j, no dependency
     sum++;
  }
}
```

The inner loop over `j` is independent of `i` and has complexity `O(N*N)`.
The outer loop does this `N` times, hence `O(N^3)` in total.

```
for (i=1, sum=0, i <= N; i++) {  // loop over i
  for (j=1; j <= N*N; j++) {     // loop over j, no dependency
     for (k=1; k<=j; k++) {      // loop over k, dependent on j
       sum++;
     }
  }
}
```

The loop over `k` is dependent on `j`. `j` loops independently over the integers up to `N*N`.
The sum `1 + 2 + ... + N * N` is equal to `(N * N + 1) * N * N / 2` which is `O(N^4)`.
Now again, the loop over `i` repeats that `N` times, hence total complexity is `O(N^5)`.

For calculating big O, always start from the innermost loop and take care of dependencies!

Comment: your formula for the sum of squares seems to be wrong. AFAIK the formula is `(n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1)) / 6` and that is in the order of `n^3`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev No, it's not the sum of squares, but the sum of integers up to the square of N. Huge difference.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Actually, I made the same mistake before writing down my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed methodically and formally using Sigma notation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's O(N^5).

The first (external) loop is O(N).

The second one is O(N^2).

The last one is also O(N^2).

Comment: The last one is dependent on the second one, so I wouldn't say it's entirely correct to mention it's running time in isolation.